# Excel VBA: How to Insert formula into an area of cells?

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem**

I need to insert some formulas into a 2 dimensional area of cells with VBA. For example below

[image: Excel Range sample]

Of course I can do this for 1 row with VBA using the .Formulas = "=Sum(....)"

but how can I include an area instead of just a range? This seems so trivial but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm trying to avoid using a loop to fill out every row.

Comment: Define what you mean by "range" and by "area". I suspect you're just confusing yourself by using two different names for what is really the same thing...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Range("yourrange").Formula = "=Sum(whatever)"
```

where `yourrange` is a Named Range, or for an actual reference

```
Range("A1:F8").Formula = "=Sum(whatever)"
```

Answer (score 2):

`range("A1:G10").formula = "=Sum(H1:H10)"`

Fill in your own range/formula