# Adding Pivot Values - further issues

Tags: excel, vba, loops, formula, vlookup

I am attempting to add VLookups into a worksheet using VBA. I have managed to get my code sort of working with the help of this group but there are still errors as outlined below.

- 1st VLOOKUP in Column AA

Typed formula would look : =VLOOKUP(B2,'Supplier Audit Report'!C:AB,26,FALSE)

- 2nd VLOOKUP in Column BB
  Typed formula would look : =VLOOKUP(U2,Pivot!A1:B1802,2,FALSE)
  Where the cells A1:B1802 is a pivot table defined as pvt
  (the size of the pivot will be different every time the macro is run so I would prefer to reference to the defined pivot table rather then A1:B1802)

I want the formula to be filled down to the end of the data in the table (again this will be to a different cell each time.

My code is as follows. I have gone through various iterations and this iteration succeeds in getting a VLOOKUP formula into AA, but not AB. However, the formula is as follows in EVERY cell of the column (i.e. the xcell reference is not changing as the formula loops and as it is text with no " " around it, it isn't bringing back a value.)

```
   =VLOOKUP(SEUR0310,'Supplier Audit Report'!C:AB,26,FALSE)
```

Where SEUR0310 isn't even the value in B2.  I want the formula to display:

```
  =VLOOKUP(B2,'Supplier Audit Report'!C:AB,26,FALSE) in cell AA2
  =VLOOKUP(B3,'Supplier Audit Report'!C:AB,26,FALSE) in cell AA3 and so on
```

When it finishes the first loop for AA, I get an error for the AB Vlookup as follows: Application-defined or object defined error. Run-time error 1004.

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix the code to get this to work. I am still exceptionally new to VBA so all your help is very much appreciated.

**Current Code**

```
    Sub Adding_VLOOKUPS()

    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim sAP As Worksheet
    Dim sDB As Worksheet
    Dim sSAR As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rMT As String
    Dim rPO As String
    Dim xcell As Variant
    Dim ycell As Variant


    Set sAP = Sheets("AP Invoice Lines")
    Set sDB = Sheets("DashBoard PO Report")
    Set sSAR = Sheets("Supplier Audit Report")

    Set pvt = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

    lastrow = sAP.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    rMT = "AA2:AA" & lastrow
    rPO = "AB2:AB" & lastrow


    Range("AA1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Matching Type"
        Range("AB1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PO Value"
        Columns("Y:Y").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Columns("AA:AB").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False




    For Each xcell In sAP.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)



        Range(rMT).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & xcell & ",'Supplier Audit Report'!C:AB,26,FALSE)"

    Next xcell


    For Each ycell In sAP.Columns("U").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)


       Range(rPO).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & ycell & ",'Pivot'!A1:B1802,2,FALSE"

    Next ycell

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things when reading through the code:
1) I'm not sure you need to write rmt = "AA2:AA". It might be enough to write rmt = "AA"

```
Range("AA1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Matching Type"
    Range("AB1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PO Value"
    Columns("Y:Y").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("AA:AB").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Why do you need this code block? It looks like you are making column labels that don't really have anything to do with putting the formula in the columns.

Also, in the for each loop you need a next statement to end the loop. This way excel knows when to iterate the cell; to go from one cell to the next cell. The work on each cell is done within the loop, but the loop needs an opening (for each cell in range) and a closing (next)

Comment: That bit of code is to label the columns and works fine. It is the code to insert the VLOOKUP I am struggling with. 

I have added the next bits for the loop, my issue is with the phrasing of the text to go in the VLOOKUP. I have now succeeded in getting the first VLOOKUP into the table, but what it is filling is not correct. I will update my code above and add further questions. 

Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: answer based on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168017/excel-vba-how-to-insert-formula-into-an-area-of-cells
try 

Range(rMT).Formula = "=VLookup(xcell, "'sSAR!C:AB", 26, False)"

with the quotation marks and equals sign added

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this doesn't seem to work at all. I have amended the questions and code above to where I am now. Thanks again for your time

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for an explanation on how those methods work? (IE how the loop works or how the range method works?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking to understand which would be the best method for my situation (either of the options or even something different) and how to write the code.

Comment: OK. The for each loop is used when you want to cycle through objects; for instance if you have an array of objects, such as pivot tables or files, then you would cycle through each object using the for each loop. The range.formula is trying to hard code in to the cells a specific formula; very good for putting it in, but not as good if you want to increment from cell to cell. To dynamically put the values in, I usually use a for loop written like this:

Comment: for i = 1 to length  --- cells(i, 27) = vlookup function. ----next i
now the next thing; do you want to add the formula into the spreadsheet, or do you want to do the vlookup calculation in the Vba?

Comment: Thank you - I want the vookup in the table.
In column AA a vlookup to cell in column B to data in a worksheet defined as sSAR.
In column AB a vlookup to cell in column U to data in a pivot table defined as pvt in a worksheet defined as sPIV.

In both cases, I want the data to fill down to the bottom of the table. This will be run weekly and each time the size of the data in the worksheet and pivot tables will be different. I have already set the macro to calculate the size of the data using code similar to following: `lastrowDB = sDB.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: and what didn't work with the other methods suggested?

Comment: I don't really understand how to write the code. 
I started with both types and read a lot of other requests for help, but then I get stuck pretty much right away. I will copy the current code above, but I know it isn't right.

Comment: Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range("A1:C100")
    rng1 = 4
    For Each cell In rng1
        cell.Value = 5
    Next

first what the code does is it initializes a range. A range is a specific grouping of cells that can have an X by Y dimension; the range is then made up of cells. It declares rng1 as this range then sets this range to be the chunk of cells a1 through c100. Think of this now as a discrete entity, this range of cells, you use it. By setting it to be 4, you've now set this group of cells to be 4. The range is obviously made up of cells.